# The file db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml was not found in

Tags: liquibase, absolute-path, file-not-found, changelog

When I run "clean compile liquibase:update" I get the error "The file db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml was not found in" followed by a list of links where the search was made. The problem is that the file is physically present. Plus, after the list of links comes the following: "Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter." Here, too, it is not clear what the error is, since I do not specify the absolute path in liquibase-maven-plugin.properties and pom file.[db.changelog-master.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3mpo.png)
liquibase-maven-plugin.properties

```
changeLogFile= db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/telegrambot?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimeZone=UTC
username= 
password= 
driver= org.postgresql.Driver

referenceUrl= hibernate:spring:ru.gb.database.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
diffChangeLogFile= src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-@timestamp@.xml
ignoreClasspathPrefix= true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>TeamDevelopment</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.gb</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dataBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven-build-timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS</maven-build-timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase-maven-plugin.properties</propertyFile>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <user.name>aleks_sap</user.name>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Deleted, re-created files, ran "clean install", nothing changes. Checked the settings.